# Type of an instance variable

Tags: python, class, member

Suppose that I have a class like this

```
class Employee:
    pass
```

I create two objects for `Employee` as below

```
john = Employee()
rob = Employee()
```

..and create instance variables

```
john.age = 12
rob.age = '15'
```

The compiler accepts both and prints the age (john's age in `int` and rob's age in `string`). How is this logical? The same data attribute having different type in each object.

Thanks.

Comment: This will result in an `AttributeError`. Either `Employee` has an attribute `age` in the class definition, or it is a descriptor.

Comment: I did not get one. It just worked; and I am able to print both the `age`s

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: No it won't. Python types need to use `__slots__` in order to enforce attribute name restrictions.

Comment: @Ignacio: Thanks for explaining, I learned something today!

Comment: "The compiler accepts both and prints..."?  What do you mean by this.  The Python compiler does almost nothing to the code.  It "accepts" nothing.  What are you suggesting here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sure to understand this fundamental principle: **in Python, *variables* don't have types. *Values* have types.** This is the essence of Python's being a dynamically-typed language similarly to Lisp and Javascript, but unlike C, C++ and Java.

```
>>> foo = 5       # foo now holds a value of type int
>>> foo = 'hello' # foo now holds a value of type string
```

Here's an excerpt from Wikipedia's [entry on typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Typing) in Python:

> Python uses duck typing and has typed
>   objects but untyped variable names.
>   Type constraints are not checked at
>   compile time; rather, operations on an
>   object may fail, signifying that the
>   given object is not of a suitable
>   type. Despite being dynamically typed,
>   Python is strongly typed, forbidding
>   operations that are not well-defined
>   (for example, adding a number to a
>   string) rather than silently
>   attempting to make sense of them.

Do read more on this subject (especially what Duck Typing is) if you want to learn Python.

---

P.S. This issue is totally orthogonal to attributes of objects. Attributes are just other "variables" in Python, which also can hold values. These values can be of different types.

Answer (score 2):

Because by saying `rob.age` you are **not** creating a class-wide data attribute that has a specific type; you are merely creating an instance-local, instance-specific attribute that refers to a concrete entity, the string `'15'`. To create a class-wide attribute you would have to say `Employee.age = …` or set `age` inside the `class Employee:` block. By setting the attribute to a descriptor, I suppose you could check its type every time it is set and restrict it to an integer or string or whatever; but in general, either a class attribute or an instance attribute is just a name for an object, and all Python cares is that `.age` names an object.

And note that Python could not really guess what you mean anyway. If you say that `john.age` is 12, you seem to want Python to guess that all other `.age` attributes should also be numbers. But why shouldn't Python go even further, and guess that they are integers — or better yet, that they are positive even integers? I really do not think it would be reasonable in any case for Python to extrapolate from a single assignment to some kind of guess as to how you will treat that attribute in all other instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's fundamentally what you get when you have a dynamically typed language.

Type is determined at runtime not at declaration.

It has advantages and disadvantages, but I believe the advantages outweigh its disadvantages in most development contexts.

(It's what Ruby, Python, PHP, etc. do)

Answer (score 1):

Python's compiler does not care what type of value you bind to an attribute/name, nor does it have to; Python's dynamic nature means that the important type checks (which are usually actually attribute checks) are done at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The term *"variable"* is  confusioning in Python.